# Gradient Descent on Function that is non-differentiable at finitely many points

Tags: optimization, numerical-optimization, gradient-descent, subgradient, non-smooth-optimization

Suppose that I have a (possibly non-convex) function that maps $R^N$ to $R$, and is differentiable at all points except finitely many points. I want to use gradient descent algorithm to show convergence to a local optima,
$$
x(k+1) = x(k) + \alpha(k) \nabla f |_{x=x(k)},
$$
where $\nabla f |_{x=x(k)}$ is derivative computed at point $x(k)$, $\alpha(k)$ is step-size at iteration $k$. When derivative is not defined, a random step is taken (say Gaussian) with variance $\alpha(k)$.

Assume that (wherever derivative is defined) the norm of derivative is uniformly bounded by $B$, i.e. $\sup_{x} \|\nabla f \| \le B$.

Is it true that the iterates converge to a local optima?

Comment: This is ill-defined : what if $f$ isn't differentiable at $x(k)$?

Comment: What do you mean by "Is this true" ?

Comment: this isn't mathematically true but might be "true in practice" for the type of gradient descent problems that arise at work if the discontinuities are mild and you understand them

Comment: @python_tensorflow thanks for mentioning my contribution if it led you to change your question : I'm getting downvoted for having helped here! ;)

Answer (score 2):

The result does hold for such a general case, even if the function has only one global maximizer. For example, there is no way to guarantee that the function does not oscillate too much, like the function $g$ such that $g(0)=0$ and $$g(x)=-(\sin(1/x)+1.5)\dfrac{x^{2}}{1+x^2},$$ for all $x\not=0$, does. This function is differentiable everywhere and have bounded derivative. In this setting,  the sequence generated by the function $g$ that starts at any of its infinite minimizer around $0$ would stay still at this critical point forever, i.e., $x^{k}=x^{k+1},$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$, whenever $x^{0}$ is a minimizer point.

---

If local optima means maximum or minimum, the function $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that
$$h(x) = x^3/(1+x^2)$$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ works if you start at the point $x_0=0.$ The sequence generated is the constant one.

---

If you want a example that the function is bounded and local optima means maximum or minimum, the function $i:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that
$$i(x) = x^3/(1+x^4)$$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ works if you start at the point $x_0=0.$ The sequence generated is the constant one.

---

The fourth and the brighter example, if local optima means maximum or minimum, the function $j:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that
$$j(x)=\dfrac{x}{1+(-x+|x|)^2}+\sin\left(\dfrac{x}{1+(-x+|x|)^2}\right),$$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R},$ is an example of differentiable function that it will be quite rare for a starting point $x_0<0$ to be such that the GD method to converge to a local maximum. This function has only one local maximum (it's global maximum as well) and yet have such behavior because of the huge amount of critical points in the negivive axis.

---

I think it's clear that there is no possible assumption that makes your result holds in such generality.

Comment: The gradient of this function isn't uniformly bounded.

Comment: I changed the example. Now the function have bounded derivative. Sorry about the little inattention.

Comment: If the sequence generated by the function $g$ starting at a local minimizer stays at a local minimizer then this is still a sequence converging to a local minimizer - this does not disprove what the OP asked?

Comment: This method searches for local maxima (local optima, in his words), hence does not work for him.

Comment: Optima means either maxima or minima, it can be either.

Comment: I will try to make a counter example with bounded derivatives. =) I believe that it is possible.

Comment: Just take $x^3$ for $x\in[-1,1]$, $-1$ for $x\in]-\infty,-1]$ and $1$ for $x\in [1,\infty[$. You can have nonsmooth points and anyways if that's a worry then you could always consider a smooth connection using e.g. splines

Comment: I added an example that is analytic.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit :** This answers the original question. The question has been edited after this answer was made.

No, this does not work :

Consider $f : x \mapsto \frac{1}{x}$, which isn't differentiable at $0$. For any positive value of $\alpha(k)$, if you take $x(k)$ whose absolute value is small enough (eg. smaller than $\alpha(k)$ and close to $0$), $x(k+1)$ will be a number with HUGE absolute value. I suspect that the sequences formed as described in *original post* will exhibit a chaotic behavior.

Comment: The norm If the derivative is not bounded.

Comment: @R.W.Prado The bound on derivative was not part of OP, which has been edited (I believe) because of this answer.